# Modulo arithmetic

Tags: abstract-algebra

This is a set of steps from the solution of a question based on the second isomorphism theorem: 
$$2\Bbb Z/6\Bbb Z = 2\Bbb Z/(2\Bbb Z \bigcap 3 \Bbb Z) \simeq (2\Bbb Z + 3\Bbb Z)/3\Bbb Z = \Bbb Z/3 \Bbb Z = \Bbb Z_3$$
I do not understand the third step. How does $2\Bbb Z+3\Bbb Z = \Bbb Z$?

Comment: Because any integer can be written on the form $2x + 3y$ where $x$ and $y$ are integers.

Comment: Hmmm that means that the chosen Z is different for each case?

Comment: @Artemisia They're the same set, but the interpretation of the plus sign in $2\mathbb{Z} + 3\mathbb{Z}$ is $\{x+y \,:\, x \in 2\mathbb{Z}, y \in 3\mathbb{Z}\}$, i.e. your compute the sum of *every* possible pair of elements in $2\mathbb{Z}$ and $3\mathbb{Z}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general $m \mathbb{Z} + n \mathbb{Z} = \gcd(m,n) \mathbb{Z}$.  See [here](http://www.proofwiki.org/wiki/Sum_of_Integer_Ideals_is_Greatest_Common_Divisor) for a proof.  The key fact, which follows from the Euclidean algorithm, is that there are $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $am + bn = \gcd(m,n)$.